# Excel VBA: Editing Waterfall Workbook in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I want to edit a (blueprint) chart I made PowerPoit via excel.

```
oPFile.Slides("charts").Select
With oPFile.Slides("charts")
    Dim t
    Set t = .Shapes("Diagramm 12").Chart
        t.ChartData.Workbook.Activate
        t.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(4, 2).Value = wksSource.Cells(67, 2).Value
end with
```

This works fine, but as soon I switch the chart to a waterfall Chart it doesn't work I get the error:

```
The Method 'Workbook' for the object 'chartData' failed (translated from germanso might be slightly differnt) 
errnumber: -2147467259
```

When I switch back to antoher chart type it works fine ( aggain)

How do I edit waterfall charts, did they forget ti put the method workbook into it?

Comment: I tried to fill the data while it is a column chart and then change it, but I can't change it to a waterfall chart
ActiveChart.ChartType = 119 ( the number I get when I debug.print ? ActiveChart.chart type) 
I do get either: The specified Dimension is not valid for the current chart type
or #5:  invalid procedure call

Comment: ActiveChart.ChartType = 119 works without an error if the chart is already   ChartType = 119 all other produce errors 

so changing from anything to 119 -> error

so changing from 119 to 119 -> fine

so changing from 119 to anything  -> fine

Comment: Waterfall charts are a relatively new format and haven't yet been included in the VBA object model.

Comment: As @JohnKorchok says, Waterfall charts and other new types (starburst, treemap, etc.) are "special". They use a newer charting mechanism which has the potential for more flexibility and performance, but which has not been integrated as well with VBA or even with Excel's user interface.

Comment: Yeah thanks - I now use a column and make my own Waterfall out of it.